# mutate() can't work with '==' using pipe operator

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R. I have tried to compare two strings and the desired output is a boolean vector. However, I am manipulating an excel file by using pipe operator and it do not work with '=='.

What did I try so far:

```
Score <- read_excel(Score_Path_LINUX)
Bool <- Score %>% 
  mutate(KEY_split = str_split(KEY, "")) %>% 
  mutate(Tim_split = str_split(Tim_Ans, "")) %>% 
  mutate(Tim_Bool = as.numeric(KEY_split==Tim_split)) %>% 
  view()
```

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `Tim_Bool = as.numeric(KEY_split == Tim_split)`.
Caused by error in `KEY_split == Tim_split`:
! comparison of these types is not implemented
```

For your information, both KEY and Tim_Ans are excel columns with 4 characters (e.g. BBSS) in each cell.
Desired output: a new column (Tim_Bool) for the result of a boolean comparison for each character,
for example:

```
KEY     <- BBSS
Tim_Ans <- BBBB
```

desired output:

```
Tim_Bool<- c("1","1","0","0")
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `dput(head(score, 10))`?

Comment: Hazarding a guess since we can't see your data, but shouldn't it be `as.numeric(KEY_split) == as.numeric(Tim_split)` instead of `as.numeric(KEY_split == Tim_split)`?

Comment: The problem is because you are trying to compare lists (as is the result of `str_split`)

Answer (score 1):

`KEY_split` and `Tim_split` are list columns. For example, if Score looks like this after reading it in from Excel:

```
structure(list(KEY = c("ABCD", "BBSS"), Tim_Ans = c("DEFG", "BBBB"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

then, your first two mutate statements create list columns, that look like this:

```
   KEY Tim_Ans  KEY_split  Tim_split
1 ABCD    DEFG A, B, C, D D, E, F, G
2 BBSS    BBBB B, B, S, S B, B, B, B
```

You can change the creation of `Tim_bool` to this:

```
mutate(Tim_bool = map2(KEY_split, Tim_split, ~1*(.x==.y)))
```

creating the following output:

```
   KEY Tim_Ans  KEY_split  Tim_split   Tim_bool
1 ABCD    DEFG A, B, C, D D, E, F, G 0, 0, 0, 0
2 BBSS    BBBB B, B, S, S B, B, B, B 1, 1, 0, 0
```

Comment: OMG, it works like magic, thank you so much. It does not come to my mind that using map2 will help... :')

Answer (score 0):

If this is your data

```
df <- structure(list(KEY = c("SBBB", "BSBS", "BSBS", "SSSS"), Tim_Ans = 
c("SBSB", "BBBB", "SSBB", "SSBS")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

df
   KEY Tim_Ans
1 SBBB    SBSB
2 BSBS    BBBB
3 BSBS    SSBB
4 SSSS    SSBS
```

Get the boolean comparison by accessing the vector within the list element produced by `strsplit`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Tim_Bool = 
           list(+(strsplit(KEY, "")[[1]] == strsplit(Tim_Ans, "")[[1]]))) %>% 
  data.frame()
   KEY Tim_Ans   Tim_Bool
1 SBBB    SBSB 1, 1, 0, 1
2 BSBS    BBBB 1, 0, 1, 0
3 BSBS    SSBB 0, 1, 1, 0
4 SSSS    SSBS 1, 1, 0, 1
```

Comment: I am using your code since this one is more direct to what I really need, thank you so much... :')